# problems running XBMC on 2011 Raspberry Pi

Tags: power, usb-power, openelec

I have a 2011 Raspberry Pi and have been trying to get openelec (v13.2 Gotham) to run on it. I am powering the raspberry pi using a Sony phone charger outputting 5V at 850mA. Whenever I plug in the USB receiver for my wireless mouse it crashes and the screen flashes on and off. Is the problem powered related, i.e. should I use a 2.0Amp Samsung tablet charger instead or do I need to get a USB hub to plug USB devices into the Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably one of two things:

- It's underpowered.  Try a bigger power supply.  If that doesn't work...
- It's caused by a voltage drop which occurs when the USB receiver is plugged in.  Some devices have this effect (I have a wifi dongle which does this).  If a bigger power supply didn't help, there's nothing you can do about this -- you must have the device attached before you boot the pi.

I suppose it could be a combination of both, although my problem with the wifi dongle persists regardless of the size of my power supply.  If you need to be plugging the USB reciever in and out, you'll have to use a hub.

Comment: So 2Amps is not going to fry my Pi, right?

Comment: 2Amps seems to work its fixed my problem, thanks so much for the help!