# How can I add an On-Off switch to my Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: python, power, switches

I want to add a on/off switch to my pi 2 to correctly shut the pi down

This is the switch I want to add:

Edit: moved from a [link](https://i.imgur.com/4OHpRSn.jpg) to be included below:
[image: A Single Pole Snap action chrome-like switch with a plate bearing the words "On" (on a Red background) and "Off" (on a black background) with wires going off out of the picture]

This guy in a Raspberry Pi kik group made this code for me

http://pastebin.com/WTeR39d8

Edit - reproduced below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import RPi.GPIO as g
from time import sleep
from subprocess import Popen

g.setmode(g.BCM)
g.setup(26,g.IN)

def p26_callback(channel):
  command = ['/usr/bin/sudo','poweroff']
  Popen(command)
  g.remove_event_detect(channel) # we've done it once, stop watching
  return

g.add_event_detect(26, g.FALLING, callback=p26_callback)

try:
    sleep(30)
finally:
    g.cleanup()
```

but he didn't explain how to wire it up. 
Also I have no idea how to add the code to the pi.

I'm running kali. I haven't tried to wire the switch or put the code in the pi because I do not know how to.

Answer (score 4):

I just finished building a power-off circuit yesterday, although mine uses a momentary switch.

Here is the python code (with attribution embedded):

```
#!/bin/python
#This script was authored by AndrewH7 and belongs to him (www.instructables.com/member/AndrewH7)
#You have permission to modify and use this script only for your own personal usage
#You do not have permission to redistribute this script as your own work
#Use this script at your own risk

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import os

gpio_pin_number=YOUR_CHOSEN_GPIO_NUMBER_HERE
#Replace YOUR_CHOSEN_GPIO_NUMBER_HERE with the GPIO pin number you wish to use
#Make sure you know which rapsberry pi revision you are using first
#The line should look something like this e.g. "gpio_pin_number=7"

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
#Use BCM pin numbering (i.e. the GPIO number, not pin number)
#WARNING: this will change between Pi versions
#Check yours first and adjust accordingly

GPIO.setup(gpio_pin_number, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
#It's very important the pin is an input to avoid short-circuits
#The pull-up resistor means the pin is high by default

try:
    GPIO.wait_for_edge(gpio_pin_number, GPIO.FALLING)
    #Use falling edge detection to see if pin is pulled 
    #low to avoid repeated polling
    os.system("sudo shutdown -h now")
    #Send command to system to shutdown
except:
    pass

GPIO.cleanup()
#Revert all GPIO pins to their normal states (i.e. input = safe)
```

The really important thing to remember is that you should have two resistors in your circuit, like so:
[image: circuit schematic]

R1 (a 10k resistor) goes to ground and keeps your chosen GPIO pin from floating, while R2 (a 1k resistor) helps prevent damage to that same pin from the 3.3V source.

Comment: Welcome to the Raspberry Pi corner of the Stack Exchanges. Good call on using edge-detection rather than polling!

Comment: @SlySven. Thank you. I spent a lot of time researching code, and AndrewH7's was the most ideal implementation. Obviously I think he did a pretty good job. :)

Comment: Excuse the noobishness, but what does the "downward facing arrow"-ish symbol on the diagram mean?

Comment: No worries! It indicates the circuit's ground.

Answer (score 1):

The code is designed to:

- monitor for activity on GPIO pin 26 (by BCM i.e. Broadcomm pin numbering), once it is set up it waits endlessly (in chunks of 30 seconds) and it will detect a "falling"-edge which is what happens to a pin that has a high pull-up and a switch connected between it and ground when the switch that is normally open is activated (pressed!)
- when such an event happens it runs the `/usr/bin/sudo` command with the argument `poweroff` and then stops waiting for any more occurrences of this event.
- eventually it will be told to terminate (by the poweroff command it happened to initiate!) and it will do any clearup actions it can do before exiting.

So you will need to wire a switch between the GPIO pin that is 26 (physical pin 37 IIRC) and rather than rely on an internal pull-up I'd also connect a 10K Ohm resistor between that GPIO pin and 3.3V.  Then you need to get that code to be run as a user with permission to use the GPIO pins - for this the root user is a reasonable choice because you do not want a normal user to interfer with it, and you want it to start when the Pi is booted up and to be running until (it tells the Pi to) shutdown.  The easiest way to do that is to paste the entire code into a (text) file and save it as something like `gpio_poweroff.py`, it will be helpful to mark it as executable with `chmod u+x gpio_poweroff.py` and place it in `/sbin` with `sudo mv gpio_poweroff.py /sbin`.  Finally you need it to be run when the Pi is started up, and that varies on something that I do not know about your system.  If it was my system I would insert the command to run it: `/sbin/gpio_poweroff.py &` into the file `/etc/rc.local` {the `&` is important, it means let it run in the background, don't wait around (for until that button gets pressed otherwise) for it to finish}.  However I am not certain that your system will have such a file - if it does then it should be Ok to use it.

Comment: Looking at the code the `sleep(30)` instruction is only there to prevent quitting the script at once. It doesn't *seem* to wait 30 seconds between detections. Event detection is immediate otherwise you'd need to keep the button pressed for 30 seconds. Anyway I'm still confused as I'd have expected an infinite loop.

Comment: Yeah it keeps running a sleep(30) in a loop I thought but now I am not so sure - as for python I hardly know my Asp from my Elbow so I'm not the *best* to rely on here... I recognise that the event detection is outside of any loop - it wouldn't be much good if you have to hold the button for up to 30 seconds before anything happened.

Answer (score 0):

You may add a power off switch to your PI so that it shuts down properly. However there's a reason, not widely advertised though, the designers didn't feature it: if you [run the system off a read-only partition](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5112/running-on-read-only-sd-card), you can safely pull the plug off the PI hence spare one precious pin.

Comment: what? i dont get it

Comment: @laxus On a Raspberry PI the need for a switch and a proper shutdown is due to Linux running non-tweaked and the risk of corrupting the SD card when pulling off the power cable. If you run Linux from a read-only root filesystem, that risk is eliminated: data corruption on the SD card results from pulling off the cable while the system writes to the SD card. No data write, no corruption.

Comment: Actually the corruption can occur in *any* file-system where pending write data is not flushed before the power is removed - `sync` is obviously reckoned to help with that, and journalled file-systems can help with the clean-up when things still go wrong.  A read-only FS obviously cannot *HAVE* any data waiting to be written to it when the plug is pulled but having all storage as fixed and unchangable is only useful in some circumstances (e.g. a public information kiosk where *nothing* the user does is saved).