# Game Server Lag Every 2 Minutes or So on Raspi 2

Tags: pi-2, server, cron

I run a DarkPlaces Quake server on my Raspberry Pi 2. Every 2 minutes or so, there is a massive lag spike in game play, but it's fine when it's not doing that. I have checked `crontab`, but neither my only user and `root` have any `cron` routines. This may just be my game server, but if it's my Pi, I would like to know.

Comment: I suppose you also have checked the system cron i.e. /etc/cron* ? The only thing that comes to my mind is the I/O flush routine but I had in memory it would rather be 4 minutes instead. Take that with a huge dose of salt. I'd try running the operating system from a read-only partition (filesystem) to see if those glitches still occur. There are procedures to reliably put the root partition read-only. Do you need one?

Comment: No, I didn't check that. Also, it definitely could have been 4 minutes in interval, time flies by when your playing a game. And yes, the OS does not need to be written to, just the server files (Blacklisting, etc.). I could definitely use an explanation on how to partition that stuff separately into read only and read/write partitions.

Comment: I also timed the lag spikes, they happen ~2 minutes between each other.

Comment: There is a Q&A on StackExchange on [how to make the PI boot off a read-only system partition](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5112/running-on-read-only-sd-card). This won't harm the PI and can be reverted in case it didn't changed anything.