# Jessie read-only won't autologin in lightdm

Tags: raspbian

I amsetting up a raspberry to run as a kiosk with a webbrowser.. I got the webbrowser to start at login, everything is working fine.. the only think I cannot get to work is the auto-login feature in lightdm when the filesystem is in readonly mode. 
When I remove the read-only from the filesystem, it will autologin and start the webbrowser as I want it to. When I set it back to read-only I get a login screen at lightdm. Anyone has experience getting the auto-login to work in lightdm?

Comment: It worked.. thanks! The trick is to install unionfs-fuse.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to mount `/home` in such a way that it is writable (if only to ramdisk).

I used [this guide](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/9135/35538) and just did the same steps I did for `/var` and `/etc` for `/home` also.